# How to use datediff function to find age range while querying?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A with date-of-birth (dd-mm-yy format) column, DOB, and suppose another table B, with data which I want to join. How can I join considering a particular age range like 18 to 25?

This is what I have written, but it's not working:

```
select * from B
inner join (select * from A
    where datediff(year, DOB, year(getdate())) between 18 and 25) A
on B.id = A.id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `datediff()` for this purpose.  Instead:

```
where dob >= dateadd(year, -25, getdate()) and
      dob <= dateadd(year, -18, getdate())
```

There are two important reasons why.  First, using a function on `dob` prevents the use of indexes and other optimizations.  That can result in inferior query plans.

Second, `datediff()` measures year boundaries.  So, it is actually returning people who were born in the *calendar* year (from Jan 1 to Dec 31) 18 to 25 years ago.  Generally, you are not interested in calendars for this purpose.